# Can Spellstrike be applied to Reach weapons?

Tags: pathfinder-1e, weapons, magus, reach

Can a Magus deliver touch spells via **Spellstrike(Su)** while using a melee reach weapon such as the whip?

> At 2nd level, whenever a magus casts a spell with a range of “touch” from the magus spell list, he can deliver the spell through any weapon he is wielding as part of a melee attack.

Whip:

> The whip is treated as a melee weapon with 15-foot reach, though you don’t threaten the area into which you can make an attack.

The weapon is "melee" however the Spellstrike doesn't mention the weapon needing to be melee, but instead the attack. (In the same sense that this wouldn't work if a melee weapon was being thrown at an opponent).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes. It isn’t clear to me why you wouldn’t think it could be. A whip, or any other reach weapon, is still a melee weapon, and is still used to make melee attacks, and as a result can still be used with spellstrike.

- The whip is found in [the table exotic one-handed *melee* weapons](https://www.d20pfsrd.com/equipmenT/weapons/#exotic-one-handed)
- The definition of [reach weapons](https://www.d20pfsrd.com/gamemastering/combat/#TOC-Reach-Weapons) says

  > #### Reach Weapons
  >
  > Most creatures of Medium or smaller size have a reach of only 5 feet. This means that they can make melee attacks only against creatures up to 5 feet (1 square) away. However, Small and Medium creatures wielding reach weapons threaten more squares than a typical creature.

  where “[threatened squares](https://www.d20pfsrd.com/Gamemastering/Combat/#TOC-Threatened-Squares)” are defined as

  > #### Threatened Squares
  >
  > You threaten all squares into which you can make a melee attack,

Comment: I can understand using a melee weapon to make a melee attack, however using a melee weapon to make a "reached" attack is what brought up the question

Comment: @DanceSC There is no such thing and you will not find that phrase anywhere in the rules.

Comment: Okay, thank you for answering this so quickly

Comment: Part of the reason too that this came to mind, and you just brought it up with the Threatened squares part, was that whips don’t threaten the area into which you can make an attack

Comment: @DanceSC Yes, that’s certainly true—but it’s also irrelevant, because the only reason threatened squares is brought up here is because I wanted to establish the connection between reach weapons threatening squares further away, and their making melee attacks. The fact that a whip *doesn’t* threaten doesn’t change the fact that reach weapons *usually* threaten, which means we know that they make melee attacks—and when whips state that they *don’t* threaten, they change nothing else about the whip, so it is still a reach weapon and therefore still makes melee attacks.

Comment: oh no I understand, I brought up the reach because the only part I was confused about was the 10-15ft area, it would make sense that a melee weapon making a melee attack at 5 ft would work. I wasn't sure about the 10 or 15ft ranges.